# django templates override: where is "Change YOUR_MODEL"

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to override the "change_form.html" django admin template and the only thing left that I can't find to modify is the innerHTML of `<h1>` "Change YOUR_MODEL" (this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5wVu.png ). I looked on all templates. Where exactly is situated that particular code line that generates the content for that h1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This HTML comes from the `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html` template.  Specifically, it's from this part of the base template:

```
{% block content_title %}{% if title %}<h1>{{ title }}</h1>{% endif %}{% endblock %}
```

Thus, the simplest way to override it is to define your own `content_title` block in your custom `change_form.html` template.  If that doesn't offer you enough control, you'll have to get into custom admin views so you can define the `title` context variable appropriately - I'd avoid that if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer you are looking for, but go into site-packages and find django. Look in django.contrib.static.admin.css.base and you'll find h1 is

```
h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #666;
    padding: 0 6px 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 .2em 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I'm trying to change the text of that particular h1, not its css